# Java 8 - Does Streams have any feature to modify the value in the Map

Tags: java, java-8

I have a scenario where when the message is retrieved from the topic, it is of the format - `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

I have to pass this list object to another processor, but before I do that, I need to modify one of the values in the map. The key of the map is "timestamp" and the value is in millisecond in EST. I need to convert this value into UTC.

And finally, create a copy of the entire list and send it over to another processor.

I Know I create a new copy using Guava Collections - `ImmutableList.copyOf(list)`.

After the copy has been created, is there anything in Java 8 streams, so I don't have to manually iterate through the list and modify the value ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Java 8 is still Java. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Are you sure a `Map` is a good fit for this problem? If all the keys in a `Map` are known, chances are that it should be a class instead.

Comment: what's wrong with a plain for loop? `for (Map<> m : list) { Object ts = m.get("timestamp"); m.put("timestamp", changeTs(ts)); }`. Using streams to mutate data often does not work so well.

Comment: @biziclop - I have no control on the incoming stream. So Map it is!

Comment: @assylias - nothing wrong with the loop, I wanted to check if I get better performance with Streams, because the incoming message rate is over 3k messages per second.

Comment: @Tunaki - What I want is being able to modify a value in that List<Map> using Streams

Comment: A list is still a list in Java 8 and if you want to do something you still need to iterate. But the Streams API gives a more concise look   list.forEach(i -> {i.put(dateKey, changeTs(i.get(dateKey)));});

Comment: @jagamot No. What you want is to modify a value in a `List<Map>`. Period. And the proper tool for that isn't a stream. You could have `list.forEach(map -> map.compute("timestamp", (k, ts) -> changeTs(ts)));` but I'd just use a `for` loop really.

Comment: There are mutative in-place methods on `Map` like `replaceAll` for this sort of thing.

Comment: @BrianGoetz - But I only want to replace a specific key in each map inside list.

Comment: You should clarify whether you want to change the original maps, having modified maps in both lists, or if you want to have modified maps in the new list only, which makes only sense if you do it *before* creating an immutable list.

Comment: @assylias: why not `m.computeIfPresent("timestamp", (key, ts) -> changeTs(ts));`…

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a copy of the list before sending it, I assume that you don't want to modify the original list or its contents, otherwise there wouldn't be much of a point to copying the list to an `ImmutableList` before sending it.  If that is the case, you might create new maps while you're building your `ImmutableList`.

The first thing you'll need is a collector that takes your `Stream` results that contain the modified Maps, and puts them into the `ImmutableList`:

```
static <T> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableList<T>> toImmutableList() {
    return Collector.of(
            ImmutableList::builder,
            (ImmutableList.Builder<T> b, T t) -> b.add(t),
            (b1, b2) -> b1.addAll(b2.build()),
            ImmutableList.Builder::build);
}
```

Then, you can stream your original list, creating modified copies of the maps as you go:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> modifiedList = listOfMaps.stream()
     .map(map -> {
          Map<String,Object> newMap = new HashMap<>(map);
              // set the new timestamp in newMap
          return newMap;   
     })
     .collect(toImmutableList());
```

That would give you a new List with the modified contents, while accomplishing the defensive copy you allude to in your post.